# Using window.location.replace is there any way to change port as well?

Tags: javascript, html, port, window.location

Using the various methods/assignments to change the browser url using js.  All work fine but whilst I can read the current port, I can't seem to set the new port - is this possible ? (I'm redirecting the browser from port 80 on one site to a node.js port on another site and don't want to use a proxy on the node box).

Cheers in advance.

N

Comment: Should have mentioned that yes, I have tried: var url="http://someUrl:portNum"; window.location = url;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I may have been an idiot ;-) Thanks nobody and Brian - those suggestions didn't work but I solved the problem. The webpage doing the redirection had absolutely no other code on it so I was at a bit of a loss as to why it was failing. However it seems I had added a

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH
```

for the redirection where javascript wasn't enabled. I had failed to add the port here and so it was this code that was doing the redirection, not the window.location stuff. Adding the port here solved the problem and is probably the right place to do what I was trying to do.

N

Answer (score 2):

This **does** work in my browser and yes I see the port number in the address bar after redirection:

```
window.location.replace( 'http://somedomain.com:1234/' );
```

and here is a alternative which also works:

```
window.location.port = 1234;
```

Comment: Ok I may have been an idiot ;-)  Thanks nobody and Brian - those suggestions didn't work but I solved the problem.  The webpage doing the redirection had absolutely no other code on it so I was at a bit of a loss as to why it was failing.  However it seems I had added a    <META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH  for the redirection where javascript wasn't enabled.  I had failed to add the port here and so it was this code that was doing the redirection, not the window.location stuff.  Adding the port here solved the problem so apologies for wasting time - cheers N.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com:1234"
```

"works" (as in, fails to connect!) for me

Comment: Brian, you've lost me - just to clarify, so what I'd said I'd tried and had failed also fails for you ?  If so, many thanks for the moral support.

Comment: @nick No, I meant it *does* work but obviously stackoverflow isn't listening on port 1234 so my browser fails to connect. If it were able to connect then it wouldn't be correctly using port 1234.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Does port 1234 come up in the address bar ?